# Rails Devise "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

everybody.

I was using Devise for authentication in Rails 4 and got some troubles with Devise. When I enter the link: http://yourdomain.com:3000/users/edit.535db919486f611779000000 , it just render the text "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing." without rendering layout, instead of redirect to login page (see attachment)

I guess Rails understand the numeric after "edit." is format and it didn't know how to render it.

What I want is when user enter any link without logged in, it will redirect to login page. Could anyone help me?

[image: Layout for devise::registration#edit not render]

With this link, it throw an unknown format exception.

[image: Wrong format]

Comment: what do you have in your application_controller, did you do a `before_action :authenticate_user!`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is to do with the passing of a value after `.` - EG `edit.234234324` or `login.23424234`

As you can see from your screenshot, you're receiving the error because Rails is treating the number as a `format` (in the same way it would treat `.html`, `.js` or `.json` as formats)

I don't know why it works for `edit`, but it looks like it's rendering `json` to me, probably because it's confused with the type of format you've sent

---

The way to fix this is to get your `config/routes.rb` & `URLs` fixed

You've not detailed how you're sending the `numbered` requests to your URL helper, but  if you're requesting pure URLS, **you need to remove the number from the end**:

```
localhost:3000/users/login
localhost:3000/users/edit
```

These are the URLs which should load (with no numbers)

I would imagine you are getting the error because you're calling the devise `url helpers` like this:

```
<%= link_to "login", user_new_session_path(some_value) %>
```

You just need to use `user_new_session_path`